# How do I get the ! icon to appear in the bottom ribbon of a group chat in MS teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

There's an (!) for important or urgent messages to be posted in a chat with another user. I dont see that when i created a group chat with multiple users. How to get that icon to appear in the bottom ribbon?

Comment: IIRC you can only do this in channels, not in chats.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DanielB see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the text input box area, and its toolbar, select the icon that looks like an A with a pen (far left) to open the expanded editor

[image]

On the new toolbar which has opened (top of the expanded editor) click the `!` icon.

[image]

The behaviour is slightly different for a Teams Channel, where the `!` icon is on the righthand side.

[image]

[image]

This then adds the `IMPORTANT` statement to the message.

Additionally, pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> will also mark a message as Important. This shortcut works for both the web client, and the desktop client.